# BeanNameAware and BeanFactoryAware

Tags: java, spring

What is the use of `BeanNameAware` and `BeanFactoryAware`? I was studying spring and came across these two interfaces.
I googled them but nothing useful came up.
Please tell me what is the functionality of `BeanNameAware` and `BeanFactoryAware` interfaces and when to use these?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `xxxAware` interface is a common pattern used within the Spring framework.  They are typically used to allow a Spring managed bean to be given an object (via the interfaces `setXxx` method) at Spring bootstrap time.

Springs documentation says this about the [`Aware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware.html) interface, which is a super interface to the two you mention:

> Marker superinterface indicating that a bean is eligible to be notified by the Spring container of a particular framework object through a callback-style method.

As Sotirious points out, the `Aware` interface has the feel of the listener, callback, or observer design patterns.

Usage would look like this:

```
@Component
public MyBean implements BeanFactoryAware {
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(final BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        //I can now use beanFactory here
    }
}
```

During bootstrapping, Spring will examine each bean to determine if it implements any of the `xxxAware` interfaces.  When one is found, it invokes the interface method, providing the piece of information that is being asked for.  In the example above, Spring calls `MyBean#setBeanFactory` providing its `BeanFactory`.

Of course, in many situations, it is not entirely necessary to use these interfaces.  For example, the `ApplicationContextAware` interface can be circumvented by simply `@Autowired`ing an `ApplicationContext` into a bean.

```
@Component
public class MyOtherBean {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void someMethod() {
        //I can use the ApplicationContext here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw in the keyword listener somewhere in your answer.

Comment: Does it mean  we can use 'beanFactory' to retrieve a bean using 'beanFactory.getBean("name")' ?

Comment: @KanwaljeetSingh What it means is that you have access to the `BeanFactory`.  You can call any method that is available to a `BeanFactory`, including `getBean`.

Comment: An `Aware` object is a `Observer`, `Listener`, `Callback` for some event. Your answer is great, it'll just be easier to find with more keywords. +1

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild If we use `getBean` doesn't that defy the entire purpose of dependency injection. Shouldn't we use the bean xml file,to inject all the dependencies of `MyBean`. Is there something else we can use this as?

Comment: @KanwaljeetSingh In general, yes, it does go against the core principles of dependency injection.  Most often, if I were to use something like this, it would likely be for infrastructure that I am building on top of Spring.

Comment: I am having a service class annotated with @Service annotation as Class A and I am implementing BeanFactoryAware in A. Now I am setting the BeanFactory using setBeanFactory method. I am trying to load a bean "B" using beanFactory.getBean method. Now in this case is it compulsory to define "B" bean in application-context.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

BeanNameAware makes the object aware of its bean name. It is best used in pre annotation config spring (2.x). You could reference the bean from a locator by its name then.

 BeanFactoryAware gives the bean access to the beanfactory that created it. For the usefulness of this, you should check the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html

Answer (score 0):

The BeanFactoryAware interface is used during the initialization of an ApplicationContext. It has been used in Spring 2 to customize the weaving of beans before they get initialized. An example would be in order to additionally add pointcuts at load time (LTW) e.g. for autogenerated find methods of DAOs. Another usage could be to load a minimized context for test, to speed up tests (lazy initialization would be a better practice)

See also http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanfactory for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

1) `BeanFactoryAware`
Bean implementing this interface can get the access to `BeanFactory` that created it
As, bean implementing this interface can get the current bean factory, this can be used to call any service from the bean factory.

2) `BeanNameAware`
Bean implementing this interface can get its name defined in the Spring container 
One possible area of use could be if your building on/ extending the spring framework and would like to acquire the bean name for logging purposes/wiring them etc.